# Searching for attribute value from XML document using Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, xml

I have around 500 XML documents in SharePoint Library and I need to search content in files.

I am able to search for values from nodes.  But I am not able to search for attributes of nodes and elements.

For example, I am able to search for word **Gambardella** but not **bk101** from below file. I need some help to make it possible search everything in the file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
  with XML.</description>
</book>
</catalog>
```